# stty before login

Tags: login, tty, hp-ux

We've got some HP-UX Integrity VMs that are difficult to log in to at the console because the `KILL` character is set to `@`, which also happens to be a component of some passwords. Now I know we can get around this by logging in as a different user, and issuing `stty KILL '^U'`, and that's already in the `.login` for all users. I also know that using `\@` will work.

The real question is what do I need to do to change the `KILL` character system-wide so that we don't either have to kludge interactive login or avoid passwords with `@`?

Comment: Either, you could find where `KILL` is set to `@`, or you could find a script that is run before you run into problems, and fix the problem there, every time (hoping you are not too early, so it is reset to `@`!). As an example, on my Debian, I would check out `/etc/inittab`. Possibly it's the same for you (I don't know HP-UX at all). Well, that's two tracks for you to follow.

Comment: I do see some stty config in /etc/inittab, but I'll have to do some reading on the init process before I start mucking about in a config file that important. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/inittab` is the place to start.  The `getty` program is used to handle the initial setup of the terminal.

According to the `getty` manual page, it has an option which can tell it to use a configuration file that lets the administrator set special characters:

> **`-f`**
>       Get the settings for special control characters from the **`/dev/ttyconf`** file. See the *Special Control Characters* section.

That section tells little, but points you to the `stty` manual page.  It has a little more information:

> The default values for the control characters may be changed by a user
>   with root capability by using **`stty`** and redirecting *stdin* to the device
>   **`/dev/ttyconf`**.  Any of the four command forms specified in the
>   *Description* section above may be used.  However, only the control
>   character defaults will be reported or altered.  It will have no
>   effect on the defaults for any of the other modes.

and gives an example:

> The command:
>
> ```
>       stty kill '^X' intr '^C' werase '^W' </dev/ttyconf
> ```
>
> sets the default values for the delete-line character to **`^X`** (Ctrl-X),
>   the interrupt character to **`^C`**, and the word erase character to **`^W`**.
>   Any terminal port opened *after* this command is issued will see these
>   new default values for the **`kill`**, **`intr`**, and **`werase`** control characters.

Given the comments about applying only to terminal ports opened *after*, that means you'd have to modify `/etc/inittab` to do this initialization.

According to a cached web search, this is answered in HP's documentation:

> *HP-UX System Administrator's Guide: Configuration Management: HP-UX 11i Version 3*
>   *Chapter 2 Configuring System Parameters*
>   *Changing Login Special Characters*

and concludes with an example line to add *before* the lines dealing with the console and terminals:

> ```
>    ttc0::bootwait:/sbin/stty intr ^C erase ^H kill ^U < /dev/ttyconf
> ```

The lines with `getty` would also have to have the `-f` option added.

Further reading:

- [inittab - script for the boot process](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man4/inittab.4.html)
- [getty  - set terminal type, modes, speed, and line discipline](http://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/B2355-60130/getty.1M.html)
- [gettydefs - speed and terminal settings used by getty](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man4/gettydefs.4.html)
- [stty - set the options for a terminal port](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/stty.1.html)